# ARCore uniqueness of the marker in the database

Tags: arcore

Good afternoon, how can the uniqueness of the marker in the database be defined in #ARCore? There were no two similar illustrations.

Answer (score 0):

The process they use is called natural feature tracking or NFT. Even though this is for a different platform this is a really good explanation of the criteria for a good vs a bad image target. As far as I know the CV doesn't take color into the equation at all. Just the shapes. You can use image markers like the old school artoolkit stuff if you want but can also do any kind of photo or image. As they outline in this link below you want to have a lot of individual variations in the image target, The more variation and detail there is in the image the better the device will lock onto the target and give you a more stable AR projection.

Keep in mind this is NOT for ARcore at all and the only info you are really looking for is regarding what makes a good image target etc. Hope this helps!

https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/Optimizing-Target-Detection-and-Tracking-Stability.html